# Why does nautilus keep asking for username / password when connecting to a SMB share? I can't connect

Tags: networking, nautilus, password, samba, sharing

I want to share a folder.

I went to the Documents folder, right clicked, turned on sharing, gave it a name.

Nautilus installed Samba and said it was working.

I navigated to the "Other locations" area and found my computer's name.

I clicked into that and found the share.

Clicked that and it asked for an anonymous connection or a registered connection.

I tried both and both times it failed.  I can't connect with any machine on the network though others can see it.

What's happening?  I've restarted the computer but still the same.  A constant request for password each time I enter and try and connect.

EDIT:  Here is the updated info as requested below:

```
$ net usershare info --long
[NUCDocs]
path=/home/rob/Documents
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your share requires a username and password to access.

So let's take the user "rob" as an example. Unlike Windows there are 2 passwords for "rob" in Linux / Samba. The local login password for that user and the samba password for that user.

You assign a samba password to that user with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a rob
```

It can be identical to the local login password if you want but "rob" needs to added the samba password database with the above command.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Finally got back to it.  It worked and makes perfect sense.  It's a shame nautilus doesn't mention this, but there it is. Done.  Appreciate your time spent helping